# Hystrix: Upping the maxSemaphoreCount for a Command?

Tags: java, concurrency, hystrix

My understanding of how `HystrixCommands` works is that the the `CommandProperties` can be changed on an ad hoc basis.

However, when I attempt to do this with the`IsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests` [property](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests) my change to command configuration doesn't seem to get picked up.

Am I misinformed about the ability to provide additional configuration for a Hystrix command that has already had configuration specified under the same key?

Is there something specific to isolation/semaphores that I'm missing in the context of Hystrix?

Below is an example of my issue.  The code starts out configuring a command that allows for a max of 1 semaphore, then bumps that number up to 2 semaphores.  At this point it attempts to utilize both of the semaphores and fails as the second can't be acquired (I'm guessing because the max allowed is still at 1?).

```
HystrixCommandKey hystrixCommandKey = HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("Command1");

// Note that we're initially setting the max concurrent requests to 1
HystrixCommandProperties.Setter maxConcurrentRequests1 = HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
        .withExecutionIsolationStrategy(HystrixCommandProperties.ExecutionIsolationStrategy.SEMAPHORE)
        .withExecutionTimeoutEnabled(false)
        .withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(1);

final HystrixCommand.Setter hystrixCommandSetter = HystrixCommand.Setter
        .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("Group"))
        .andCommandKey(hystrixCommandKey)
        .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(maxConcurrentRequests1);


class SleepOneSecond implements Callable<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return (new HystrixCommand<Boolean>(hystrixCommandSetter) {
            @Override
            protected Boolean run() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(2_000);
                return true;
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
threadPool.submit(new SleepOneSecond()).get();

// Bumping up the command settings to 2
hystrixCommandSetter.andCommandPropertiesDefaults(
        maxConcurrentRequests1.withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(2));

// We should be allowed to have two concurrent commands now because we've bumped our semaphore cound up to two for
// these commands...
for (Future<Boolean> result :  threadPool.invokeAll(ImmutableList.of(new SleepOneSecond(), new SleepOneSecond()))) {
    result.get();
    // Instead on the second result we end up with a:
    // com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: Command1 could not acquire a semaphore
    //   for execution and no fallback available.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from Github issue [#1048](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1048) :

The issue here is the granularity of how properties apply. Per-command key, there is a single properties instance for that key. All commands of that key get that config. This is done to reduce operational burden. If there were a variety of command instances with differing config (say timeout values), this would be a very hard system to operate, tune, and understand.

However, it's also important for these values to be tweakable. Hystrix offers Archaius integration, which will allow you to modify the semaphore count (or any other config value) at runtime. When you do this, you're modifying the singleton properties instance, and all commands pick this value up. See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration for more details on how this integration works.

Comment: Hey @mattrjacobs, could you possibly include an example of how one might update a Command's property after initial execution of a command (via the Archaius integration)?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do so, depending on what pieces of technology you want to leverage.  The Archaius model is to poll a configuration source.  It ships with a variety of known-working config-sources, and you're free to add others by implementing the proper interface.  https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Users-Guide